# How to get GridBagLayout to line up correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I have a JPanel as a viewport for a JScrollPane, and the JPanel has a GridBagLayout. The user of the program will be able to add rows to the JPanel, and the JPanel will expand accordingly. It expands all right, but when it doesn't need to be expanded, it doesn't add them in the order I would like. I'm trying to achieve:

```
 ______
|XXXXXX|
|XXXXXX|
|      |
|      |
|      |
--------
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
 ______
|XXXXXX|
|      |
|XXXXXX|
|      |
|      |
--------
```

and then:

```
 ______
|XXXXXX|
|      |
|XXXXXX|
|      |
|XXXXXX|
--------
```

Once it runs out of room, it will expand and the JPanels align correctly.

I tried setting the `weighty = 0.9` to get the desired effect, and I have the anchor property set to `NORTHWEST`, but I'm getting the second result. Is the desired effect possible within a GridBagLayout?

Comment: I think you want `weighty = 0` and/or don't FILL. Fill and weight is only for situations where you want the components to expand to fill the available space.

Comment: That aligned the components together, but now they are added to the center of the JPanel. Is there a way to make them anchor to the top? (anchor is set to NORTHWEST currently)

Comment: Add a "spacer" (I use `new JPanel()`) to the third row, give it a `weighty = 1` and `fill = VERTICAL`.  This empty panel will then expand to fill the space below your two rows of visible elements.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one component needs a `weighty=1`, so add a spacer item at the end with a `weighty=1`. All other components should have `weighty=0`. Otherwise the `GridBagLayout` does not know how to distribute the remaining space and distributes it equally to all components.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `weighty = 0` and/or `fill = NONE` for your components. Fill and weight is only for situations where you want the components to expand to fill the available space, but you want your components to fill only the space they naturally need.

Then, to gather all of the "empty" space at the bottom, add a "spacer" (I use new JPanel()) to the third/next row.  Give the spacer `weighty = 1` and `fill = VERTICAL`. This empty panel will then expand to fill the space below your two rows of visible elements.